# Android Activity onNewIntent while remaining in background

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to have activity handle onNewIntent while remaining in the background? I have activity that mostly remains in the root and receives calls within onNewIntent from activities outside the app (it's in singleTop mode). Everything works fine as long as there are no additional activities on top of mine, but as soon as I launch another activity - those external calls to my root activity bring the activity back to top.

Ideally I would prefer to process those onNewIntent calls in the background without my activity coming to foreground.

Answer (score 0):

you might change your way to send message to that root activity, sending broadcast to it will work fine.